Summation of infinite terms yields negative result
Today, while solving a question in my homework, I stumbled upon a strange thing that I couldn't wrap my head around. I am not more than an amateur in mathematics, so I could barely understand the few other articles on SE with the same pattern of the question.
Consider,
$$S = 1 + 9 + 9^2 + 9^3 + 9^4 + \dots \tag{1}
$$
$$9S = 9 + 9^2 + 9^3 + 9^4 + \dots \tag{2}
$$
Subtracting we get ,
$-8S = 1$
Or , $S = -\frac{1}{8}$
but clearly, $S = 1 + 9 + 9^2 + ...> 0$. So how can $S$ be $-\frac{1}{8}$?
I asked my teacher about this, who said that this series gives "accurate" results only when $|x| < 1$. However, I am yet to understand what actually went wrong in my derivation. Clearly $S$ tends to infinity, but then one line below, due to some atrocious mathematics done by me, it says otherwise.
I want to know what the "atrocious mathematics" is in this case. Almost seems like the proofs concluding $0 = 1$, where they commit a fallacy by dividing by $0$.

In general it is not true that $x(y_1+y_2+y_3+\cdots)=xy_1 + xy_2 + xy_3 + \cdots$. The series is the limit of the partial sums so you have to be sure the partial sums make sense before you distribute.

Since you've just started learning about series, you've probably just seen formulas like $1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^n + \cdots = \frac{1}{1-x}$ without any context whatsoever.
The fallacy that you're making is assuming that $S$ even exists in the first place! Not all series actually have a finite sum:

Series with a sum are called convergent
Series without a sum are called divergent

The series $S=1 + 9 + 9^2 + \cdots$ is in fact divergent. So multiplying $S$ by nine makes no more sense than asking "What is the color red times 9?"
When your teacher says that "this series gives 'accurate' results only when $|x|<1$" what they really should be saying is that the series only has a sum when $|x|<1$.

Worth pointing out in OP's case that they have $x=9$, which is far away from the convergent range.

You could use the extended real numbers (that is, you include $\infty$ and $-\infty$) so that $S$ is well-defined and equals $\infty$. But then you can't subtract the two equations, as $\infty - \infty$ is not defined (it's like how you can't just divide by a variable when working with real numbers, because the variable might be zero).

Thanks for your answer . So the main takeaway is that when writing infinite series like this , we should always specify $|x|<1$ , like we say $x \neq 0$ when dividing by 0 ? Otherwise we could conclude that the sum doesn't even exist .

That is correct, @MikeBillings. The analogy is apt. In both cases you're trying to play with mathematical objects that don't exist.
